# Bootstrap responsive queries not working the way I'm trying to get

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create this following responsive design for my webpage with bootstrap:
[image: Photo]

This is so far what I've done:

```css
.header {
    background-color: #9933cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menu li {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header">
   <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-3 menu">
      <ul>
         <li>The Flight</li>
         <li>The City</li>
         <li>The Island</li>
         <li>The Food</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
      <h1>The City</h1>
      <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
      <div class="aside">
         <h2>What?</h2>
         <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
         <h2>Where?</h2>
         <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
         <h2>How?</h2>
         <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
   <p>The Footer</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the problem is, the content doesn't respond to the screen size change as visualized in the image. I have been trying to achieve it but couldn't find what should I do to make it right.

Thanks in advance for the suggestion.

Comment: None of your code suggests any responsive changes. You're overriding Bootstrap's Column class and not specifying any media size breakpoints. Have you reviewed the Grid documentation? http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Do have an other look at the bootstrap documentation. Only applying col-* doesn't make a website responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bootstrap 4, you have various different sizing structures. Right now you are using `col-{1-12}`. This sets the sizing for all screen sizes.

What you actually need to do is utilise the `col-{screen-size}-{1-12}` css classes. I've amended your snippet (very loosely) to reflect what you are asking. The various sizes available are `xs` `sm` `md` `lg` and as of 4 `xl`.

See - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#responsive-classes

```css
.header {
    background-color: #9933cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menu li {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #0099cc;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #0099cc;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="header">
<h1>Chania</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 menu">
        <ul>
            <li>The Flight</li>
            <li>The City</li>
            <li>The Island</li>
            <li>The Food</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <h1>The City</h1>
        <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
        <div class="aside row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">
                <h2>What?</h2>
                <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">
                <h2>Where?</h2>
                <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">
                <h2>How?</h2>
                <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>The Footer</p>
</div>
```